# How to compare two multidimensional arrays by certain keys in each?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays of the same structure.

Like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(9) {
    'id' =>
    string(5) "44994"
    'ersatzteil_id' =>
    string(3) "120"
    'lang' =>
    string(6) "name2_tag2"
    'title' =>
    string(12) "Seitentüren"
    'alias' =>
    string(12) "seitentueren"
    'content' =>
    string(1610) "LOREM ISPUM BLALABLBL"
    'on_main' =>
    string(1) "0"
    'disabled' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'short_text' =>
    NULL
  }
  [1] =>
  array(9) {
    'id' =>
    string(5) "44996"
    'ersatzteil_id' =>
    string(3) "122"
    'lang' =>
    string(6) "name1_tag1"
    'title' =>
    string(7) "Spoiler"
    'alias' =>
    string(7) "spoiler"
    'content' =>
    string(1513) "SOME OTHER RANDOM TEXT"
    'on_main' =>
    string(1) "0"
    'disabled' =>
    string(1) "0"
    'short_text' =>
    NULL
  }
}
```

What I need to do is I need to compare first array with the second one. 
I have to compare them by keys `ersatzteil_id` and `content` , and I find that they have same content I need to store element from first array in another new array, that wasn't existing before.

For example I need something like this, but more efficient:

```
    if(array1[20]['ersatzteil_id'] == array2[145]['ersatzteil_id'] 
       && array1[20]['content'] == array2[145]['content']){
      array3 = array1[20];
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [array_uintersect](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) or [array_uintersect_assoc](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-assoc.php).

Comment: Why do you think your code isn't efficient enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
$result = [];
    foreach($array1 as $arr1){
        foreach($array2 as $arr2){    
            if(($arr1['id'] == $arr2['id']) && ($arr1['ersatzteil_id'] == $arr2['ersatzteil_id'])){
                $result[] = $arr1;
            }
        }
    }

echo '<pre>';  print_r($result);
```